Searching is now case sensitive
We have noticed that searches in CiviCRM are case sensitive.  Searching for community and Community return different results.  The documentation says that text searches are case insensitive.  Searches in our development install are not case sensitive.  In the past, searches worked fine.  Running verison 5.75.1.
Does anyone have any suggestions on what would be causing it?  I have reviewed search preferences and looked at extensions, but can't find a reason why it behaves this way.  This is like it in quick search and advanced search.

The collation in your database tables may have changed. While unusual for it to magically change it would explain it.
Try e.g. show create table civicrm_contact; in phpmyadmin or whatever tool you use to manage the database and check what it says for collation. The expected value is utf8mb4_unicode_ci. The "ci" means case insensitive.

Thanks for the answer. It was a collation change that caused the problem.
